# Instagram - "Client request limit reached"

Tags: api, client, limit, instagram

I am using Instagram's API for my app. All of the users have to authenticate once the first time they open the app and then they can "like" photos. So every user uses his own Access_token in the like request. The Problem is that in a short period of time we all can't use like. After many many many hours we can use it again but only after few hours we get the error again.

The authentication for Access_token is with like scope.

Like request is like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/*mediaID*/likes?access_token=*access_token*
```

The ratelimit for my access_token in the Response headers is for example like this:

`X-Ratelimit-Limit: 5000  X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 4997.`

And this is right because I did not send more requests in that hour. Only 3. But I and all of the other users with their specific token are getting the error whenever we want to like a Picture:

Error message when liking although we NEVER had reached the Limit:

```
"Client request Limit reached" Error Code is "400"
```

Why do we get this error message? I know how many api calls my app did and it is waaay lower than 350 per hour per Access_token. And why "Client" reached limit? I am using Access Tokens so why the error message says "Client"? The app uses the ClientID only once to authenticate. I think they ban all of the Access_tokens that are linked to my clientID. But I don't know why. And why do they block every acces_token and also the ones which were NOT using the app for hours. After not using the app for hours I am still getting the same message.

This happens again and again. The app is useless for now.

I looked for Loops or strange code in my app causing many requests but it is fine and it is not spamming. I would really appreciate your help because Instagram never responded haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this Problem by Messaging Instagram (apidevelopers@instagram.com I think it was). You have to ask them to whitelist your app. For me it took only 1 workday but I think I was lucky. It could have gone much longer like 2 months.

You also can fill up form using http://help.instagram.com/contact/438525166257277

Answer (score 0):

You can also Post your details http://help.instagram.com/contact/438525166257277

AS per the comment above, it will take longer time. Instagram not providing quick response on blacklisted IP/App.